# How do I access my JSON data in Javascript from an ASP sub

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I need your help. How do I go about accessing my JSON data that my ASP sub has created and use it in a Javscript enviroment? My goal is to eventually use the JSON data to render a datatable. I unsure as to how to access the ASP variable JSON using javascript to manipulate the data later.

Here is the code that is working:

```
<%
    sub search
    
         Dim cn
         Dim rs
         Dim sSQL
         Dim JSON
    
    
        set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    
        cn.Open "ConnectionString"
    
        sSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_offices"
    
        set rs = cn.Execute(sSQL)
    
        JSON = RStoJSON(rs)
    
        response.write(JSON)
    
        response.flush
    
        rs.Close
        set rs = nothing
    
        cn.close
        set cn = nothing
    
    end sub
    
    %>
```

I'd like to access the stored JSON data in my Dim JSON using JavaScript

```
<form name="GO" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Search" class="input_txt_search" />
    <input type = "submit" name="GO" value="GO"/>
</form>


<%
    if Request.Form("GO") = "GO" then           

        search

    End If
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can output the JSON like this to be used in the html later:

```
response.write("<script>")
response.write("var obj = " & JSON)
response.write("</script>")
```